# creating open tr and td jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble converting inline html in my javascript to jquery.

I want to avoid inline scripts so firebug will not show the entire script in one row and instead keeps the formatting.

Basically i have this at the moment:

```
var zeile2 = $("<tr id='wle_focusout_"+paramDataObject.id+"'>" +
        "<td><input id='wle_input_seconds_"+paramDataObject.id+"' type='text'/> </td>" +
        "<td><input id='wle_input_height_"+paramDataObject.id+"' type='text'/> </td>" +
        "<td><input id='"+get_waterlevelevent_del_btn_name(paramDataObject.id)+"' type='button' value='"+languagebox.editor_wleRemoveBtn_header+"'/> </td>" +
        "</tr>");
```

One tr with 3 tds, each td has an input element in it.

So far I converted each element on its own:

```
var wleFocusOut = $(document.createElement('tr')).attr({
       id:      'wle_focusout_'+paramDataObject.id,
       });

var wleInputSec = $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
       id:      'wle_input_seconds_'+paramDataObject.id,
       type:    'text'
       });

var wleInputHeight = $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
       id:      'wle_input_height_'+paramDataObject.id,
       type:    'text'
       });

var wleDelBtn = $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
       id:      get_waterlevelevent_del_btn_name(paramDataObject.id),
       value:   languagebox.editor_wleRemoveBtn_header,
       type:    'button'
       });

var wleTempTd = $(document.createElement('td'));
```

However those jquery elements are closed (without body content).

How can i create an open () version with jquery that allows me to add(just append?) the tds, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
var zeile2 = 
    $('<tr/>', {'id':'wle_focusout_'+paramDataObject.id}
    ).append(
            $('<td/>').append(
                    $('<input/>',{
                        'id': 'wle_focusout_'+paramDataObject.id})
                    )
    ).append(
            $('<td/>').append(
                    $('<input/>',{
                        'id': 'wle_input_seconds_'+paramDataObject.id,
                        'type': 'text'})
            )
    ).append(
            $('<td/>').append(
                    $('<input/>',{'id': 'wle_input_height_'+paramDataObject.id,
                        'type': 'text'})
            )
    ).append(
            $('<td/>').append(
                    $('<input/>',{'id': get_waterlevelevent_del_btn_name(paramDataObject.id),
                        'value':    languagebox.editor_wleRemoveBtn_header,
                        'type': 'button'})
            )
    );
```

With this different syntax it does work and firebug does not assume this beeing inline script.